# Retrieve/store all options of a dropdown list using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, listboxitem

I need to check all values of a dropdown list one by one to verify the new option is present in the list or not.
For that, I am trying to select all items of the dropdown list in a 'LIST' and loop through it, but it is not working.
I tried below:
dropdown =  select(driver.find_element.....)
dropdown.options

I also tried using normal XPATH, with list items' tagname as the last-part of XPATH.
It works for a grid but not for the dropdown list.
Tried a few different ways, but nothing seems to be working.

How can I check if a particular value/item is present in a Static-dropdown list using Selenium+Python?

Comment: please post the code snippet you've tried along with the URL if possible, otherwise the HTML snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example